# How to make a scene remeber an int value Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple project. A button adds points one at a time to a counter. I then change the scene via another button and return to the original scene. The point counter has gone back to zero. How do i prevent this?

Comment: Save the value to PlayerPrefs when it is changed and load it when the scene is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to achieve this. But for starters you can save the number in Player Prefs.

"PlayerPrefs` is a class that stores Player preferences between game sessions. It can store string, float and integer values into the user’s platform registry"

So forexample this is your button callback function:

```
public void ButtonCallback()
{
    number++;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyNumber", number);
}
```

To get the number next time you are in the scene, you can get the number using:

```
int number = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyNumber");
```

You will probably need to check if number exists in the first place when you launch the scene first time using:

```
PlayerPrefs.HasKey("MyNumber");
```

Read up more on this on:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html